# What it would look like to observe people with a different time flows?

Tags: gravity, universe, observational-astronomy, space-time, general-relativity

As I learned, that the bigger gravity source you are influenced by the more slow time ticks for you, the farther away you are from a gravity source the faster times ticks.

So Imagine two different planets where on each people live, one planet is massively big (time ticks slow), the other one very small compared (time ticks faster). How would it look like for bigger planet people to observe smaller planet and for smaller planet people to observe them. Hope it makes some sense.

Comment: [Cross-posted to Physics](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/150390/what-it-would-look-like-to-observe-people-with-a-different-time-flows).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Normal case:**

The effect would not be very noticeable unless the large planet was extremely large / high gravity (e.g. it would look "almost" normal) looking at one another.  If the planet was that large, it would probably not be able to support life, but to see what would happen, lets assume it can support life.

**Relativistic case, from the large planet, observing the small planet**:

If the large planet were extremely "heavy / massive" (think more like a neutron star), the people on the large planet would observe the people on the small planet moving much faster.  It would be like watching a movie with "fast forward" on.  However, light would also be blue shifted, which would produce other interesting visual effects (e.g. what was red might now be blue, and what was in invisible "infrared" might now be red depending on the amount of the shift.)  The amount of blue shift (light wave compression) and "fast forwarding" would increase if the planet were made bigger.  The rest of the universe would have similar effects when observed from the large planet.

**Relativistic case, from the smaller planet, observing the large planet**:

The people on the smaller planet would observe the people on the extremely large planet moving in "slow motion".  It would be like watching a movie in slow motion.  The people on the large planet would also be "red shifted".  For example, something that was blue might appear red, and something in the ultraviolet range might now appear blue.  The "slow motion" effect and red shift (light wave expansion) would increase if the extremely large planet were made bigger.

Comment: Very interesting, I had some similar thoughts. Thank you.