# If you are in a deep gravity well, where time goes by more slowly, do you see the unfolding of a cosmic event at a different rate?

Tags: gravity, time-dilation

If you were on one of those planets orbiting a super massive black hole (ala Interstellar), where time is moving more slowly, would you time astronomical events differently or even the age of the universe?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/32440/16685

Comment: Note that the time dilation in *Interstellar* is so high because the planet is orbiting deep within the gravitational well of a SMBH with extreme spin. The odds of such a planet existing (and being habitable) are very small.

Comment: With sufficiently accurate clocks, a deep gravity well is not required to detect the effect: https://cdn.danielbmarkham.com/reference/original-articles/nerd-roundup/2021-10-29/resolving-the-gravitational-redshift.pdf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Time dilation is related to differences in gravitational potential in General Relativity.

Observing a clock situated deep in a potential well, a distant observer would see it running slow. Vice-versa, an observer looking outwards from within a deep potential well would see distant clocks running faster.

The situation is complicated by orbital motion. This results in a time dilation that would be predicted by Special Relativity. Any relative motion will make a moving clock appear to run slower to an observer in a stationary frame.

To keep things simple, a stationary observer at a radial coordinate $r$ around a non-spinning black hole, would observe events far away from the black hole speed up by a factor $(1 - r_s/r)^{-1/2}$, where $r_s$ is the Schwarzschild radius (and is the smallest radius at which a stationary observer could possibly exist).

However, you would only make incorrect estimates of durations and ages (by using times on your own clock) if you didn't understand General Relativity.